# DirectX D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain always Failed

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, device

I am trying to make a simple project on DirectX.

I have create 3 class DXManager, DX10Manager and DX11Manager.
[image: Class Diagram]

I am following the french tutorial : [HERE](http://sebastiencourtois.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/directx-1011-tutoriel-2-cration-dun-device-direct3d/).

When I try to initialize my swapchain, the function "D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain" failed (release & debug).

This is the message return by the function : "-2005270527" and m_swapChain stay empty.

This is the link dropbox to my project : [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/87cxrjtf00rhza4/JtPGNY4I3l)

I have searched on many sites, but I didn't found yet a solution.

Thanx for your help and I wish you a good weekend.

Best Regards,

Clément.

```
//init DirectX
bool DX10Manager::Init (HWND* _hWnd)
{
    this->m_hWnd = _hWnd;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect (*_hWnd, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.top - rc.bottom;

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //SwapChain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    //2buffers (back buffer et front)
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    //(60 fps)
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;

    //Multisampling setting
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *_hWnd;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //Device
    HRESULT codeError = S_OK;
    codeError = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain ( NULL, 
                            D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                            NULL,
                            D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
                            D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
                            &swapChainDesc,
                            &this->m_swapChain,
                            &this->m_D3DDevice);
    if(FAILED(codeError))
    {
            this->Error("Error Device 3D.");
            return false;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //renderTargetView
    ID3D10Texture2D* backBuffer;
    if(FAILED(this->m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (LPVOID*) &backBuffer)))
    {
            this->Error("Error backBuffer.");
            return false;
    }
    if(FAILED (this->m_D3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, NULL, &this->m_renderTargetView)))
    {
            this->Error("Error render target view.");
            return false;
    }
    backBuffer->Release();
    this->m_D3DDevice->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &this->m_renderTargetView, NULL);

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //viewPort
    m_viewPort.Width = width;
    m_viewPort.Height = height;
    m_viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    m_viewPort.MaxDepth = 0.0f;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftX = 0;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftY = 0;
    //assignation du viewPort
    this->m_D3DDevice->RSSetViewports(1, &this->m_viewPort);

    return true;
}
```

[EDIT]

I have found my error, for compute the height of my window, I substracted the top to the bottom and the result was negative, this is the good compute : UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top; Thanx for your helps guys.

Comment: If you compile in debug mode, there should be a more detailed error message somewhere. What does it say?

Comment: Your error message is:  DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL
0x887A0001

The application provided invalid parameter data; this must be debugged and fixed before the application is released.

Comment: Which might not be super useful but does suggest you have an argument wrong

Comment: Are you certain that you have a DirectX10-capable GPU?  Also, `D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` requires that the debug layers be installed (should be included with the SDK).  Verify that `d3d10sdklayers.dll` is present in your `Windows\System32` folder.  Note that you should use that flag only for debugging, and should remove it for your release build.

Comment: Hi and thanx everyone,
@NicoSchertler : this is the error message on Debug : 
"DXGI ERROR: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: No target window specified in DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC, and no window associated with owning factory. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #6: ]"
I don't know what's wrong with my swapChainDesc. I have found on a subject that the color format could be the problem but I have the same format than the solution of this topic...

Comment: @Rob : when I lauch it on Release, the DX Device is not create, I have a blank window.
Like I have said, I follow a tutorial so I hope he didn't put any mistakse in him subject...

Comment: @MooseBoys : I can play every sample of the DirectX SDK, I have install the Windows 8 SDK to play some DX11 samples who didn't work without that. The DLL "d3d10sdklayers.dll" is in the right place. Should I have to link it in my project in debug mode?

Comment: Does your `hwnd` hold a valid value? It seems that this might be the problem. Do you get reasonable results from `GetClientRect()`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler : I have checked, GetClientRect return nothing and my variable hWnd have an adress but when I try to spy it, visual says that it's unused. This my code who init hWnd :
hWnd = CreateWindow( "TutorialWindow", windowName.c_str(),WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,width,height,NULL,NULL,_hInstance,NULL);
My test " if(!hWnd) return false;" return true. I have discovered that "ShowWindow" return a boolean and it return false for my case.
So I have to take a look in that way...

Comment: I have found my error, for compute the height of my window, I substracted the top to the bottom and the result was negative, this is the good compute :
UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;
Thanx for your helps guys.